# Complex Mongo query in Python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a collection named `measurements`. In this collection, there are only three fields: `id` (univoque), `tmstamp` (univoque) and `value`. Each row which contains a value greater than 0 is considered an alert. All the alerts that occur from the zero state to the next zero state is considered an episode. I want to query the data in such way that it returns it in episodes format. That is to say, each row is an episode.

In order to make it easier to understand, I'll put an example:

```
{"id":1, tmstamp:1577644027, value:0}
{"id":2, tmstamp:1577644028, value:0}
{"id":3, tmstamp:1577644029, value:1}
{"id":4, tmstamp:1577644030, value:1}
{"id":5, tmstamp:1577644031, value:2}
{"id":6, tmstamp:1577644032, value:2}
{"id":7, tmstamp:1577644033, value:3}
{"id":8, tmstamp:1577644034, value:2}
{"id":9, tmstamp:1577644035, value:1}
{"id":10, tmstamp:1577644036, value:0}
{"id":11, tmstamp:1577644037, value:1}
{"id":12, tmstamp:1577644038, value:1}
{"id":13, tmstamp:1577644039, value:1}
{"id":14, tmstamp:1577644040, value:0}
```

Given this data, the episodes would be:

`episode1`:

```
{"id":3, tmstamp:1577644029, value:1}
{"id":4, tmstamp:1577644030, value:1}
{"id":5, tmstamp:1577644031, value:2}
{"id":6, tmstamp:1577644032, value:2}
{"id":7, tmstamp:1577644033, value:3}
{"id":8, tmstamp:1577644034, value:2}
{"id":9, tmstamp:1577644035, value:1}
```

`episode2`:

```
{"id":11, tmstamp:1577644037, value:1}
{"id":12, tmstamp:1577644038, value:1}
{"id":13, tmstamp:1577644039, value:1}
```

My question is: is there any way to query the data in Mongo in order to obtain the result in this format without having to do these operations after the query itself?

Comment: perhaps [`$bucket`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/bucket/) achieves this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to combine `$facet` and `Array expression operators`.
 
As **@aws_apprentice** mentioned, `$bucket` will do it for you if you know previously **zero-state measure id's**, as [**boundaries** don't accepts expresions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/bucket/).

So, we need to separate zero-state and non-zero-state data. Let's call them: *alerts* (value = 0) and *episode* (value > 1).
For `alerts`, we store `_id` of each measurements with alerts into array (we need it to filter episodes). With `$indexOfArray` and `$arrayElemAt` we can take next _id<sub>`i+1`</sub> (filter episodes between <sub>`i`</sub> and <sub>`i+1`</sub> ids).

**ASSUMPTION**

I've replaced `id` to `_id` to perform aggregation
You know how to translate MongoDB aggregate command in `Python` syntax

```
db.measurements.aggregate([
  {
    $facet: {
      alerts: [
        {
          $match: {
            value: 0
          }
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "",
            ids: {
              $push: "$_id"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      episodes: [
        {
          $match: {
            value: {
              $gt: 0
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$alerts"
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      alert_idx: "$alerts.ids"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$alerts.ids"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "k": {
        $concat: [
          "Episode",
          {
            $toString: {
              $indexOfArray: [
                "$alert_idx",
                "$alerts.ids"
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "v": {
        $filter: {
          input: "$episodes",
          cond: {
            $and: [
              {
                $gt: [
                  "$$this._id",
                  "$alerts.ids"
                ]
              },
              {
                $lt: [
                  "$$this._id",
                  {
                    $arrayElemAt: [
                      "$alert_idx",
                      {
                        $sum: [
                          {
                            $indexOfArray: [
                              "$alert_idx",
                              "$alerts.ids"
                            ]
                          },
                          1
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "v": {
        $ne: []
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OXAo0kgIJxl)